# gulp-connect doesn't work on gulp watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I've just started to learn `gulp` and I'm trying to use `gulp-connect` https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect.
This is my files structure
[image]

And it's my `gulpfile.js` file

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css'),
minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
notify = require('gulp-notify'),
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
connect = require('gulp-connect'); 

// server connect   
gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: [__dirname],
    livereload: true
  });
});

// css
gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/*.css')
    /*.pipe(notify('Done!'))*/
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['> 1%', 'IE 7']
        }))
    .pipe(concatCss("style.css"))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(rename('style.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

//html
gulp.task('html', function(){
    gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

// watch
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('css/*.css', ['css']);
  gulp.watch('index.html', ['html']);
});

// default
gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'html', 'css', 'watch']);
```

I don't undestand why all works correctly when I use command `gulp` in node.js console, but if I try to use command `gulp watch` I get an error in browser console
`http://localhost:8080/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

[image: http://i.imgur.com/4hTYaBI.png]

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're not running 'connect' task when running 'watch'.

Reformat your tasks like this

```
gulp.task('watch:assets', function () {
  gulp.watch('css/*.css', ['css']);
  gulp.watch('index.html', ['html']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'html', 'css', 'watch:assets']);
gulp.task('watch', ['connect', 'watch:assets']);
```

Go back to terminal and run

```
gulp watch
```